# water effect in a view based application

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, effects, distortion

I'm using a view based application in xcode and I would like to do an effect: water effect like this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aix1QbE9m0w) .In this video the guy use opengl es And I don't know it it's possible without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code is use for the water drop effect,

```
-(IBAction)btnActionTapped:(id)sender{
    CATransition *animation=[CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setDuration:1.75];
    [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[animation setType:@"rippleEffect"];

    [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeRemoved];
    animation.endProgress=0.99;

        imgV.hidden=YES;
        imgV2.hidden=NO;


    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
}
```

Comment: what is yepNop=YES; exactly ? :)

Comment: This for the displaying the view flag uses

Comment: Can you shortly explain what datatypes imgV and imgV2 are and why it is necessary to set them hidden or not?