# UIView with water effects

Tags: iphone, ios5, quartz-core

I am making a view based application where i wish to give water effect to the view. 
Please help me.

I am using following code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rippleEffect" context:NULL]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0]; 
[UIView setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransition)110 forView:view cache:NO]; 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: what you have to tried ???

Comment: i tried to give ripple effect but thats not working

Comment: [UIView beginAnimations:@"rippleEffect" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransition)110 forView:view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: edite your Question with your code so, all the developers can see it.. and help you :)

Comment: hey @user1926201 try with my answer its helps you if you wish while your UIView load This effect fired you just called this IBAction with `[self btnActionTapped:self];`

Comment: @user1926201 - use **Nitin** anser it is worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can set View `WaterEffect` by tapping Button i just Google it and i got Answer [FROM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377427/water-effect-in-a-view-based-application)

- First You need to add `QuartzCore.framework` in your Project from Target->Build Phases-> link Binary with library click on + button.
- `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in .m file

Now implement this IBAction of BUTTON

```
-(IBAction)btnActionTapped:(id)sender{
    CATransition *animation=[CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setDuration:1.75];
    [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[animation setType:@"rippleEffect"];

    [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeRemoved];
    animation.endProgress=0.99;
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
}
```

Comment: yes, it is working. However, you should say that this is a private API

Comment: Is it possible that once we click the button the effect remains forever

Comment: What's the problem with "private API"?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with a private API. However if you don't know what the API is.....